# Making parsed json data interactive

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

Hope someone can help. I am parsing json data using jQuery  `$.parseJson`.  I get an error when I get **undefined** when I tried to load the "Address" portion. (I have also tried adding (obj,obj1 (function
but that does not work.

I tried hiding the var `jsonp` after the content loads because I want when each "Name" is clicked for the address to then display. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonp = '[{"Name":"Abc", "address":"111"},{"Name":"Xyz","address":"222"}]';
    var sName = '';
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonp);
    $.each(obj, function () {
        $(this).click(function(){
            alert("this");
        });
        sName += '<p>';
        sName+= '<a href="">';
        sName += this['Name'] + "<br/>";
        sName+= '</a>';
        sName += this['address'] + "<br/>";
        
        sName += '</p>';
        
    });
    $('span').html(sName);
     jsonp[2].style.display="none";
     jsonp[4].style.display="none";
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12pt;
    padding : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```

Comment: You are attempting to read a property named `address` from an object that doesn't contain it. Remember you're iterating `jsonp`, not `jsonp2` - it's the latter that contains addresses, not the former. You appear to have correlation between names and addresses, unless you are simply assuming an indexed link (e.g. name at index 5 correlates to address at index 5.)

Comment: ok, I modified the code a bit. It now pulls the address information.

Comment: also modified the code to attempt to hide the address information on load but am not selecting it correctly